# Akka actors' state not monitored properly

Tags: scala, akka, actor

**Monitoring Akka actors' state** is said to be possible by using *.underlyingActor*.

In the example below, there is an ***ActorWithState*** using an **Integer counter**. The process of counter's incrementation and decrementation is tested by an ***ActorWithStateTest***. The incrementation step always passes. However, counter's decrementation does not seem to work in that the 2nd assert always fails. The error message is the following. **What is wrong?**

**[Error message of this test]**

```
[info] ActorWithStateTest
[info] - should validate counter incrementation and decrementation *** FAILED ***
[info]   1 did not equal 0, Expected counter to be 0 after 'Terminated' message
```

**[Actor with counter]**

```
        object ActorWithState {
          case class Inc;
        }

        class ActorWithState(snooper: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
           var counter = 0

           def receive = {
               case Inc             => counter += 1 
               case Terminated(ref) => counter -= 1
           }
        }
```

**[ActorTest shall test counter's behaviour]**

```
class ActorWithStateTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("SimpleTestSpec")) {

  "Test" should {
    "validate counter incrementation and decrementation" in {

      val aws = TestActorRef(Props(classOf[ActorWithState], testActor), name = "aws")
      val awsA: ActorWithState = aws.underlyingActor

      // tell aws to increment its counter
      aws ! ActorWithState.Inc

      // this assert always passes
      assert(awsA.counter == 1, ", Expected counter to be 1 after 'Inc' message")

      // triggers a 'Terminated' message being sent to aws
      val tp = TestProbe()
      aws    watch tp.ref
      system stop  tp.ref

      // [EDIT] the following assert passes if some - time consuming - processing is added here

      // the following assert does NOT pass, WHY?          
      assert(awsA.counter == 0, ", Expected counter to be 0 after 'Terminated' message")
    }
  }
```

*[akka-actor: 2.3.2, akka-testkit: 2.3.2, scalatest: 2.0]*

Comment: The stopping of an actor is asynchronous, so your assertion is more than likely happening before your actor has received the `Terminated` message.  I will advise with a solution shortly.

Comment: Agreed, further observations revealed the following: If I do some processing in the test before the assert, it usually passes. The whole set-up falls back to the more general question then "How to properly test an actor's state", right?

Comment: Answer: you don't, at least not directly. The only relevant behavior is what the Actor sends in messages, if your state is not observable that way then you should not test it either. TestActorRef was meant to more easily get an Actor into the test's initial state, nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, your issue stems from the stopping of an actor being async.  Your assertion is happening before the `Terminated` message hits your actor that you are testing.  One quick and dirty way to fix this is to introduce another probe that also listens for the terminated event and perform an assertion on that first.  That will wait until the terminated is received by the second watcher which should mean that your actor has also received the terminated event and you can perform your assertion.  This worked for me:

```
  val tp = TestProbe()
  val tp2 = TestProbe()
  aws    watch tp.ref
  tp2    watch tp.ref
  system stop  tp.ref
  tp2.expectTerminated(tp.ref)

  assert(awsA.counter == 0, ", Expected counter to be 0 after 'Terminated' message")
```